# Symfony : Erreur with try catch

Tags: symfony, try-catch

it's the first time that I publish so I don't know if I respect all the modalities. Please excuse me in advance.

When a user registers with an already registered email I get an error because my email must be unique.
So I have to intercept the error to avoid which crashes my site

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo0o8.png)

I tried to put a try catch in order to catch the error but I think I misused it after several searches without result, if someone could help me

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow :D A good practice when posting on this site is to introduce your code. We can't copy paste from an image, so we can't point you a potential mistake.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a [UniqueEntity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) constraint in your `Utilisateurs` entity.